# Laravel Call to undefined method App\\Http\\Models\\User::posts() while it exists (Redis Queued Listerner)

Tags: php, laravel, redis, event-listener

I got this error in my application, even though I already searched on Google but there is no question like this. It's weird.
Error:

```
BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Call to undefined method App\\Http\\Models\\User::posts() at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php:5
```

This is my User.php

```
class User extends Model
{
...
    public function posts(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

PostListener.php

```
class PostListener implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function handle(PostCreatedEvent $event)
    {
        $user = User::find($event->id);
        $user->total_posts = $user->posts()->count();
    }
}
```

This is my `.env`

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_CLIENT=predis
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_PREFIX=
CACHE_PREFIX=cache
```

As I mentioned above, it throws an exception. But after removing `implements ShouldQueue` in `PostListener.php`, it works well.

Anyone faced with this issue before, please help me

Comment: why is that model in the `App\Http` namespace?

Comment: @lagbox because I put the `models` folder inside of app `folder`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a really good reason, which doesn't seem you have, prefer eager loading instead of lazy loading. You can solve your problem like this:

```
$user = User::withCount('posts')->find($event->id);
```

[Here is the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#aggregating-related-models).

Comment: Thanks, @Bulent, I think that those give the same result

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved already. I believed that it should be Redis issue since I tried other drivers of queue, and it worked. After trying to restart worker, it worked well for me.
Thanks all. This is my script:

```
php artisan queue:restart
```